# socket.io-client on('message') not working

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I am using socket.io-client in a react native chat application. The socket connects fine and it responds to on('connection') but it doesn't respond to messages. What is the proper way to configure socket.io-client to handle custom events? All the documentation I find looks like my implementation. My messaging module:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
Messenger = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [test, setTest] = useState('');

  const socket = io('https://test.com', {
    autoConnect: false,
  });

  const getCredentials = async () => {
    await socket.connect();
    await fetchMessages();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.connect();

    socket.on('connect', function() {
      setTest('connected!');
    });

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
      setTest('message!');
    });

    socket.on('typing', function(typing) {
      setTest('typing');
    });
    getCredentials();
  }, []);

  return (...);
}
```

My server:

```
var socket_io = require( 'socket.io' );
const io = socket_io();
io.use((socket, next) => {
  sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
});
io.on( "connection", function( socket )
{
  if (socket.request.session.auth_user) {
    redisClient.set(socket.request.session.auth_user._id.toString(), socket.id);

    socket.on( "disconnect", function() {
      console.log( "A user disconnected" );
      redisClient.del(socket.request.session.auth_user._id);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say without seeing your server but if comparing your case to my case it should be something like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io('https://test.com', {
        autoConnect: false,
    });

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        setTest('connected!');

        socket.on('message', function (message) {
            setTest('message!');
        });

        socket.on('typing', function (typing) {
            setTest('typing');
        });
    });
```

}, []);

Comment: I added the server code. The code I am using in react native is the same code I use in my functioning desktop client.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `socket.emit('message',...)` in your server in order to catch the message on your client app?

Comment: I use socket.emt('message',...) in a messaging function later in the code.

Comment: I just realized my server doesn't recognize connections from react native.

Comment: You sloved the problem? Do you run the server in localhost?

Comment: I didn't solve the problem but I now know that my server isn't handling connections from react native correctly. My server is running on an EC2 instance.

Comment: Is there a reason why socket.io wouldn't handle the connection event for socket.io-client specifically?

Comment: Not that i know of